# Javascript getelementbyId iframe consolidation

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, getelementbyid

I am admittedly new to Javascript, so grace is appreciated...

A. I want to apply the `getelementbyId` function (I think) **WITHOUT** JQuery, and

B. I want to apply it to the whole table, but each element has different hover images or states... any help much appreciated!

```
<code>
<article class="main_display">  
<p style="text-align: center;"><iframe id="bigVideo" width="850" height="500" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/45587075?rel=0&autoplay=0&modestbranding=1&wmode=Opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<table width="142" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" id="mouseOvers">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#" onclick="$('#bigVideo').attr('src', 'http://player.vimeo.com/video/46124645?rel=0&autoplay=1&modestbranding=1&wmode=Opaque')" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image7','','http://s3.amazonaws.com/worship/graphics/worshipmadness/play_rollover.jpg',1)"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/worship/graphics/worshipmadness/week1_vid.jpg" name="Image7" width="140" height="142" border="0" id="Image7" /></a></td>
    <td><a href="#" onclick="$('#bigVideo').attr('src', 'http://player.vimeo.com/video/46117474?rel=0&autoplay=1&modestbranding=1&wmode=Opaque')" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image2','','http://s3.amazonaws.com/worship/graphics/worshipmadness/play_rollover.jpg',1)"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/worship/graphics/worshipmadness/week2_vid.jpg" name="Image2" width="142" height="142" border="0" id="Image2" /></a></td>
    <td><a href="#" onclick="$('#bigVideo').attr('src', 'http://player.vimeo.com/video/46117474?rel=0&autoplay=1&modestbranding=1&wmode=Opaque')"  onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image3','','http://s3.amazonaws.com/worship/graphics/worshipmadness/play_rollover.jpg',1)"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/worship/graphics/worshipmadness/week3_vid.jpg" name="Image3" width="142" height="142" border="0" id="Image3" /></a></td>
    <td><a href="#" onclick="$('#bigVideo').attr('src', 'http://player.vimeo.com/video/46119637?rel=0&autoplay=1&modestbranding=1&wmode=Opaque')"  onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image4','','http://s3.amazonaws.com/worship/graphics/worshipmadness/play_rollover.jpg',1)"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/worship/graphics/worshipmadness/week4_vid.jpg" name="Image4" width="142" height="142" border="0" id="Image4" /></a></td>
    <td><a href="#" onclick="$('#bigVideo').attr('src', 'http://player.vimeo.com/video/46121214?rel=0&autoplay=1&modestbranding=1&wmode=Opaque')"  onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image5','','http://s3.amazonaws.com/worship/graphics/worshipmadness/play_rollover.jpg',1)"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/worship/graphics/worshipmadness/week5_vid.jpg" name="Image5" width="142" height="142" border="0" id="Image5" /></a></td>
    <td><a href="#" onclick="$('#bigVideo').attr('src', 'http://player.vimeo.com/video/46123371?rel=0&autoplay=1&modestbranding=1&wmode=Opaque')"  onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image6','','http://s3.amazonaws.com/worship/graphics/worshipmadness/play_rollover.jpg',1)"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/worship/graphics/worshipmadness/week6_vid.jpg" name="Image6" width="142" height="142" border="0" id="Image6" /></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</p>
</article>
</code>
```

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish, as well as show us the code you're currently working with. Both will go a long way toward getting help.

Comment: thanks, sorry, the code didn't post correctly... but now we're good.

Comment: What do you expect getElementById to do?

Comment: @scrappedcola I want the items in the table, to replace "bigVideo" when clicked.

Comment: Replace big video with what? Are you tryrng to rewrite the jquery with plain javascript? You question is very vague. Please think of the 5 W's when asking for help: Who, What, Where, Why, and When. Don't just say "it doesn't work"; don't just say "I want to apply this function". Where do you want to apply it? How do yo expect it to work? How does it work now? What have you tried? How does it apply to the code you showed?

Comment: I want each of the table images, when clicked, to replace the 'bigVideo' div id with the attributed src of the table image.
and yes, i want it to be done without jquery, with straight javascript. @jfriend00's script returned 0 errors and it didnt load the clicked attributed source into the bigVideo Id div.

Does that make sense?

Comment: The suggestion in my answer seems to work for me in this jsFiddle using your HTML combined with my code suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/5cqgj/.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is: "How do you replace the jQuery in your table that is in the `onclick` handlers with plain javascript", then you can do so like this:

```
<td><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('bigVideo').src = 'http://player.vimeo.com/video/46124645?rel=0&autoplay=1&modestbranding=1&wmode=Opaque')" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image7','','http://s3.amazonaws.com/worship/graphics/worshipmadness/play_rollover.jpg',1)"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/worship/graphics/worshipmadness/week1_vid.jpg" name="Image7" width="140" height="142" border="0" id="Image7" /></a></td>
```

It seems to work for me here in this demo using your HTML/code: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/5cqgj/

If you meant to ask something different, please clarify what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm in Chrome and that didn't work. When I click, nothing happens.

Comment: @lsaintj - when you respond to the repeated calls to describe EXACTLY what you're trying to accomplish, we might be able to help you better.  When you say "nothing happens", did you look in the error console to see if any errors were reported?

Comment: @lsaintj - my code suggestion seems to work for me in Chrome in this jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/5cqgj/.

Comment: ok, sweet this works (with a little edit to some conflicting calls on the page)
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use CSS for rollovers:

```
<style>
      #Image2 div, #Image3 div, #Image4 div, #Image5 div, #Image6 div, #Image7 div { width:142px; height:142px; }
      #Image7 div { width:140px; } /*is it suppose to have a different width than the others? and is the id suppose to be "Image7" and not "Image1" ?*/
      #Image2 div { background:url(http://s3.amazonaws.com/worship/graphics/worshipmadness/week2_vid.jpg); }
      #Image3 div { background:url(http://s3.amazonaws.com/worship/graphics/worshipmadness/week3_vid.jpg); }
      #Image4 div { background:url(http://s3.amazonaws.com/worship/graphics/worshipmadness/week4_vid.jpg); }
      #Image5 div { background:url(http://s3.amazonaws.com/worship/graphics/worshipmadness/week5_vid.jpg); }
      #Image6 div { background:url(http://s3.amazonaws.com/worship/graphics/worshipmadness/week6_vid.jpg); }
      #Image7 div { background:url(http://s3.amazonaws.com/worship/graphics/worshipmadness/week1_vid.jpg); }       
      #Image2 div:hover, #Image3 div:hover, #Image4 div:hover, #Image5 div:hover, #Image6 div:hover, #Image7 div:hover { background:url(http://s3.amazonaws.com/worship/graphics/worshipmadness/play_rollover.jpg); }
</style>
```

Create a function for your video changer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function bigVideo(src) { // this is regular javascript no JQuery
        var url      = 'http://player.vimeo.com/video/';
        var settings = '?rel=0&autoplay=1&modestbranding=1&wmode=Opaque';
        document.getElementById('bigVideo').src = url + src + settings;
    }
</script>
```

Doing this cleans up your html quite a bit.

```
<article class="main_display">  
    <p style="text-align: center;">
    <iframe id="bigVideo" width="850" height="500" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/45587075?rel=0&autoplay=0&modestbranding=1&wmode=Opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    <table width="142" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" id="mouseOvers">
      <tr>
        <td><a id="Image7" href="#" onclick="bigVideo('46124645');"><div></div></a></td>

        <td><a id="Image2" href="#" onclick="bigVideo('46117474');"><div></div></a></td>

        <td><a id="Image3" href="#" onclick="bigVideo('46117474');"><div></div></a></td>

        <td><a id="Image4" href="#" onclick="bigVideo('46119637');"><div></div></a></td>

        <td><a id="Image5" href="#" onclick="bigVideo('46121214');"><div></div></a></td>

        <td><a id="Image6" href="#" onclick="bigVideo('46123371');"><div></div></a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    </p>
    </article>
```

Recap:

1- Replace "img" tags with empty "div" tags and passed the id to the "a" tags.  This allow us to use background images for rollovers with css.

2- Create a function to replace the video source and keep within the function all the data that doesn't change and pass the changing variable to the function.

This results in cleaner html.  Ideally you want to try to keep your html css and javascript separated. Even your table has attributes that can be passed to css.

Comment: Awesome, this is EXACTLY what I needed. Thank you so much. I know this is super basic, but i can see HOW you did it as well, which rocks!
Thanks @Damian

Comment: @Isaintj - There was a typo in my code for the function call "bigVideo", just noticed it "setttings" needed to be "settings".